# Unity 2d biome generation(with different tiles in each biome)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, noise

I found an excellent [tutorial](https://code2d.wordpress.com/tutorials/) for generating a 2d world.

I want to add biome generation to it and so that each biome has several types of tiles (for example, in the desert, tiles of sand and salt (something like dried seas), on the plain, tiles of grass, mud; etc.)

I would be grateful for any advice or links to tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

For each material, you can assign a noise function with different parameters (frequency, offset, octaves, ...) and for each biome, an ordered list of the materials. Then For each tile, you can loop through the materials of it's corresponding biome to check if the value of the current material's noise is above 0 and if it is the case, apply it (sometimes by overwriting the previous one). Like that the materials will be added layer after layer. Note that you have to assign a default material just in case none of the materials have a noise value above 0.